# what is this.data() in meteor or iron-router

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a project that someone already developed and I saw this code

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
             if(this.data()) {
                this.subscribe('edition', this.params.editionId).wait();
             }
        },
        data: function() {
                var editionId=this.params.editionId;
                var edition = Editions.findOne({"permalink":editionId})
                if(!edition)
                    edition = Editions.findOne({_id: editionId})
                return { 
                    edition: edition 
                };
        }
```

what is `this.data()` functionality here? I never heard about it in meteor. Is this the correct way to do this?

I changed it to the following and faced few issues and resolved them :)

```
onBeforeAction: function() {

                this.subscribe('edition', this.params.editionId).wait();
        },
        data: function() {
            if(this.ready()){
                var editionId=this.params.editionId;
                var edition = Editions.findOne({"permalink":editionId})
                if(!edition)
                    edition = Editions.findOne({_id: editionId})
                return { 
                    edition: edition 
                };
            }
        }
```

which one is better? and why? what is this `this.data()` all about

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the two are any better than the other -- each serves a different function, though seemingly similar.

`this.data()` returns the data context of the route, which is essentially the stuff you're returning from the `data` function inside of your route.

On the other hand, `ready` returns a boolean to signify that the subscriptions you are waiting on have returned (or otherwise called `this.ready()`). The result of `ready` tells us *when* the data is returned, but offers little insight into the actual data.

So, even though both can be used to 'wait' for the results of the subscriptions, the important thing to note here is that a subscription could be 'ready' but the resulting 'data' could be falsy/null (e.g. the result of visiting a `/posts/:_id` route with a fake `_id`).

A good illustration of the difference between the two is the `dataNotFound` plugin that ships with IR, in which you might see something along the lines of the following (simplified for sake of explanation):

```
Router.hooks.dataNotFound = function () {
  if (!this.ready()) { // ready() call
    this.next();
    return;
  }

  var data = this.lookupOption('data'); // data() call
  ...

  if (!data) {
    this.render('notFoundTemplate');
    return;
  }
  ...

  this.next();
};
```

Using the `ready` call (which reruns whenever the state changes), we wait for the entire subscription waitlist to finish, and then we check whether or not the data is any good. If not, we render a 'notFound' template, otherwise we just call `this.next()` to move onto the next hooks.

Hopefully this helps.